# USB RS232 turn on/off beamer

Tags: python, usb, display

I'm streaming a video to a beamer. But I want it too turn it off after office hours.

I found `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o` and `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p` to turn off the screen. But that does not turn off the beamer (I can still see the light is on)

I guess I can switch on / off the beamer using serial communications. There is a a port on the beamer for RS232, I could not find documentation for this specific beamer.

So I bought a usb to RS232 cable.
When I plug it in I see `/dev/ttyUSB0` appear.

I [found](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47450/gui-program-for-turning-on-off-a-projector-via-rs232), [some](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8224/detecting-tv-power-on-off-without-cec), [python](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=139813), [scripts](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=202041) but I can't figure it out.
It appears I would need [Pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) And I installed that one already

`cat /dev/ttyUSB0` returns nothing.

Where do I start? I'm not familiar with Python (mostly a php programmer)

Comment: So you can switch on / off the beamer using serial communications?

Comment: I guess? There is a a port on the beamer for RS232, I could not find documentation for this specific beamer

Comment: You really will need documentation if you want to do anything with the device over RS232 (or even if you want to see if it's possible). If possible it will have specific commands to do different things. As an example, from the python scripts you linked below  ON=bytearray([0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02]) this is the ON "command" for their specific device.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the serial cable approach, but does the beamer have a remote control? If it does, you could make a little IR blaster to turn it off.

Something along the lines of [this](https://www.hackster.io/austin-stanton/creating-a-raspberry-pi-universal-remote-with-lirc-2fd581) or [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Universal-Remote/) would work, as long as the pi was within sight of the beamer.

Once you'd configured the IR blaster with the codes for turning the beamer on and off, a small script could startup/shutdown the beamer and video at the same time.

I made one (with Arduino but similar principle) as a beginner project a while back and the components required cost pennies.